# Can I reference multiple regex items with one expression?

Tags: r, regex

I'm using R and I'm trying to clean up a string.

```
 string <- '{\n  \"bigint\": \"aaa6d928-aaaa-3333-5555-8598e3c78d7a\"\n}'
 a <- str_remove_all(string, '"')
 b <- str_remove_all(a, "\\{") 
 c <- str_remove_all(b, "\\}") 
 d <- str_remove_all(c, "\\n")  
 e <- str_remove_all(d, "\\s+")
```

I would like to place these in one `str_remove_all` statement. I've tried to chain together filters like this `('"' | \\{)` and `['"'] | [\\{]` and neither of those worked.

How do you reference different parts of the same string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can place it inside square brackets

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(string, '["{}\n ]+')
#[1] "bigint:aaa6d928-aaaa-3333-5555-8598e3c78d7a"
```

or use `gsub` from `base R`

```
gsub('["{}\n ]+', "", string)
#[1] "bigint:aaa6d928-aaaa-3333-5555-8598e3c78d7a"
```

which is similar to

```
e
#[1] "bigint:aaa6d928-aaaa-3333-5555-8598e3c78d7a"
```

Comment: Beautiful. I noticed you didn't include `\\s`. I assume the `+` operation works on all of the items in the square brackets and, since you included a space, it gets rid of all the spaces. Is that right?

Comment: @tadon11Aaa  The  space at the end `n ]+` stands for space